# Do Linux flavored OS systems support a Window Explorer quick navigation feature to find files?

Tags: linux, gui, file-manager

I'm irritated on having to navigate completely through the GUI folder file system with the GUI folder view.

Is there any way within the GUI to just pass the path to where I want to look and explore or must I always navigate the complete path via clicks on the File Explorer of the GUI?

I understand that I can use the terminal, but I'm wanting to do this with the Folder viewer.

Comment: Note: I am using CENTOS 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specifics vary depending on which file manager you’re using.

In GNOME, in a “Files” window, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> will allow you to type or paste a path; <kbd>Enter</kbd> will then go to that path.

Answer (score 1):

## Change directory by typing in dolphin file-manager

- Option 1: Click the address bar (location bar) or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>, and type the path.
- Option 2: **Open the integrated shell, and use `cd` command. The file-manager will also change directory.** (Does not work if your dolphin is too old. You have to use the terminal that is integrated with dolphin.)
- Option 3: Search within the current directory, by just typing (I don't like this, because there are timeouts).
- Alternative (or to use as well as) : Add short-cuts to the places pane.

Answer (score 0):

In Konqueror, the KDE file manager, there is a box for it displayed (see red arrow).
[image]

Thunar (my personal favorite) also displays the location bar:
[image]